# RelativeLayout or LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development, and I am unable to understand why it is not working as per desired output.
The desired output and the output I am getting are shown below as well as the ml layout.

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5mJy.jpg)

[image]

[Achieved output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Hzv.jpg)

[image]

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.caringhumans.rds.caringhumans.MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/caring"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caring"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Caring Humans"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#f70f59"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/child"
    android:src="@drawable/child"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/caring"/>
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Campaign"
    android:textColor="#f70f59"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/child"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: RelativeLayout, it will help you later in supporting multiple screen sizes

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Caring Humans"
        android:textColor="#f70f59"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/child" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/child"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Campaign"
        android:textColor="#f70f59"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is with image trying fixing that and your problem can be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, your code worked perfectly fine, only change which I made to resolve the image was to add android:scaleType="fitXY" .

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayouts are used for placing your Views in a linear shape, either in a row or in a column.
The latter seems to be what you are after.

RelativeLayouts are used when you want to place the positions of your Views in a non linear way, rather using a relation between them (toRightOf, above, or similar).

Comment: I thought of using LinearLayout but then I wasn't able to understand how to center the text "Caring Humans" and place the logo before it.

Comment: To "place the logo before it" you can use a **compound drawable** (the image will be **inside** the TextView and you can get rid of the ImageView - less Views, the better performances). To align the contents of the TextView to the center you can use `android:gravity="center"`.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the Imageview to really "wrap" around the image you are displaying you need to add these two attributes

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

as for the parent layout here you should probably use LinearLayouts (you will need to add to them `android:orientation="vertical"` as the default one is horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"

  tools:context="com.caringhumans.rds.caringhumans.MainActivity">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/logo"
android:src="@drawable/logo"
android:layout_width="28dp"
android:layout_height="28dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/caring"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/caring"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Caring Humans"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:textColor="#f70f59"/>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/child"
android:src="@drawable/child"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/text"
android:layout_below="@+id/caring"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Campaign"
android:textColor="#f70f59"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding following two tag into [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) with id 'child' can resolve your problem.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

FitXY scale the image using fill
and you need to set adjustViewBounds to true to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/child"
android:src="@drawable/child"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_height="256dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/caring"/>
```

This would help you to achieve desired layout. Increase height of image according to your needs. :)